# C99 syntax colouring

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

I submitted a [proposal patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=143) to [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to highlight C99 types such as `int8_t`, `uint32_t` etc. Regardless of what upstream thinks of the patch, I believe this could be a nice addition to the SO syntax highlighter.

Comment: Just so people know, SO uses Google Code Prettify to syntax highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked patch was accepted by google-code-prettify, so this should now be fixed. (Assuming SO is using the latest version.)